# How to make vim to load specific colorscheme automatically?

Tags: vim, osx-yosemite

New to vim here. 
I'm trying to use vim on OSX 10.10.5.
Every time I do `vim somefile` it opens the file with default colorscheme.

My theme file is **~/.vim/colors/customtheme.vim**.

adding `colorscheme customtheme` to **~/.vimrc** doesn't do the trick and I'm wondering why?

I've tried adding:

```
if &t_Co >= 256 || has("gui_running")
    colorscheme customtheme
endif

if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
    " switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
    syntax on
endif
```

And got just syntax highlighting but the colorscheme is still default((
Any ideas?

Comment: Does your colorscheme apply after opening a file and then doing `:colorscheme customtheme`?

Comment: yes. If I do it manually it applies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem.
I had another colorshemefile.vim in **~/.vim/plugin/**. 
So moved it to **~/.vim/colors/** and my conditional with `if &t_Co >= 256 || has("gui_running")` started to work as it should work…

It probably happens because plugins load after colors. And themes have the same file extensions (.vim) as plugins so vim doesn't make a difference between them… So if there are any colors in the **~/.vim/plugin/** directory then they have a "priority"

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the if-condition to set your colorscheme. 
Before setting your scheme set `t_Co` to `256` if your terminal supports it. I assume you use a terminal because you said that you do `vim somefile`.

`set t_Co=256` tells vim to use 256 Colors if your terminal supports it. It normally isn't set to `256` by default. And since you are not running GVim your if-condition is never true, thus not setting your colorscheme. Replace the if-condition with:

set t_Co=256
coloerscheme customtheme

Comment: It doesn't work(( Returns: `E518: Unknown option: colorscheme`

Comment: Thanx for attempt to help!